# Called Mail() without being connected Mailed Error

Tags: php, email

Hey i am working on sending mail to users. I used the code below it was working fine some days back but today when I opened and tested my code it started to give error. Please solve my problem.

```
include "PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail -> IsSMTP(); 
$mail -> SMTPDebug = 1; 
$mail -> SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail -> SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail -> Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail -> Port = 465; 
$mail -> IsHTML(true);
$mail -> Username = "nida.office123@gmail.com";
$mail -> Password = "*************";
$mail -> AddAddress($to,$nameM );
$mail -> Subject = "Payment Request";
$mail -> Body    = "<b>A payment request has been made. Please visit your panel and accept or disapprove the request.Visit the link below to perform the action. <center><a href=\"http://localhost/internshippro/login.php\">Login to continue</a></center></b>";
$text = 'Text version of email';
$html = '<html><body>HTML version of email</body></html>';
$file = 'index.php';
$crlf = "\n";
$hdrs = array(
    'email' => 'example@gmail.com',
    'Subject' => 'Test subject message',
    'comment' => 'Test comment',
);
if ($mail -> send($hdrs))
//if (mail($subject,$message, $headers))
{
    echo "<script> alert('Thank you for contacting us!');window.location = '';</script>";
} else {
    echo "Mailed Error: " . $mail -> ErrorInfo;
}
```

And the error which comes is

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
>
> The following From address failed: root@localhost : Called Mail() without
>
> being connected Mailed Error

Comment: `$mail->setFrom('you@example.com', 'First Last');`